# System wide sysinit.vim but in lua

Tags: neovim, lua

`sysinit.vim` works like a charm, but  I want to fully transit into lua.

How file should be called? `sysinit.lua` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is [not supported](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/22595), but you can [execute lua code inside vimscript](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html).

```
lua << EOF
  -- your lua code
EOF
```

Comment: By my reading of the linked issue, this (or at least, calling a lua file from sysinit.vim) is in fact the recommended way to do this, so saying it's "probably not supported" doesn't seem right to me. +1 anyway for solving the problem. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

For system wide init in lua you could have a `init.lua` in `{dir}/nvim/init.lua` where `{dir}` is any directory in `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`.

More information with: `:help config`

Comment: But `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is typically `$HOME/.config/`. So it's not a system wide config file location.

Comment: Also, I haven't tested this, but [the documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#VIMINIT) reads to me like if you have a regular user init.lua in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME then any ones in $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS won't be read, so I don't think this will work at all, regardless of the actual locations.